# what is the file that contains the default application icons list for the unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

can anyone tell me the name of the file which contains the default icons list for Unity launcher? 
I am assuming it will be a .conf file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.gschema.xml` (the *favorites* key).